# Storing Session values for captcha's

Tags: php, session, captcha

I'm trying to create a captcha code but the code that is being created isn't being stored in the session variable.  Here is the file I'm using to create the code and store the value.  I have a session_start() on my php page that will display the captcha as well.

```
<?php session_start();
class CaptchaSecurityImages {

var $font = './monofont.ttf';

function generateCode($characters) {
    /* list all possible characters, similar looking characters and vowels have been removed */
    $possible = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
    $code = '';
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $characters) { 
        $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
        $i++;
    }
    return $code;
}

function CaptchaSecurityImages($width='120',$height='40',$characters='6') {
    $code = $this->generateCode($characters);
    /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
    $_SESSION['security_code'] = $code;
    $font_size = $height * 0.75;
    $image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');
    /* set the colours */
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
    $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 120, 180);
    /* generate random dots in background */
    for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
        imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
    }
    /* generate random lines in background */
    for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
        imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
    }
    /* create textbox and add text */
    $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $this->font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
    $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
    $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
    /* output captcha image to browser */
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
}

}

$width = isset($_GET['width']) ? $_GET['width'] : '120';
$height = isset($_GET['height']) ? $_GET['height'] : '40';
$characters = isset($_GET['characters']) && $_GET['characters'] > 1 ? $_GET['characters'] : '6';

$captcha = new CaptchaSecurityImages($width,$height,$characters);

?>
```

I can store other items in sessions and they work just fine.  I'm not sure why this value won't store. I've found other posts about getting captcha's working but nothing about issues with storing the value in sessions. Any suggestions?

Thanks
Robert

Comment: If this is for production code, have you looked into [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)?

Comment: I've run into the same problem with one of my sites, weird thing is I've got it working on about 10 websites and this one doesn't save the session.. you could comment the output lines (header + imagejpg + imagedestroy) and print_r($_SESSION) to see if it's stored when you run the file.

Comment: Thanks Austin, I'll look into that.  That's what I'm running into Pendo, I'm not sure if it's something to do with setting the header's for the image value or what's going on but it seems weird that it would work in some places but not this one.

Comment: can you add the code you are using to display?

Comment: Here is the URL where I downloaded the code from.  Even using the exact files that is in the download don't work.  http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-captcha.php

Comment: @Pendo taking out those lines (header + imagejpg + imagedestroy) it stores the value, when putting the lines back in it doesn't store the code.

Comment: @Austin reCAPTCHA works great.  I don't really like the HTML code it generates as it looks funny on my form but I might be able to play with that a little and use it.  I would like to figure out why this isn't work.  Thanks again.

Comment: Curious why the `header()`, `imagejpg()`, and `imagedestroy()` calls are causing the value to not be stored in the session.  Once you push the value into the session, it should be there.  Only 2 of those methods write data to the browser, and I can't see why the `header()` would matter, because the client already has the session cookie (so the subsequent write on this page isn't really required) and the output from `imagejpeg` shouldn't effect any session storage on the server. neither of these methods delete the session cookie..so it's really really strange (at least, to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did end up using reCAPTCHA to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

How is your image being loaded into the user's browser?  Is it on the same domain?  If it is not, the problem most likely is that your cookie is being excluded because it's a "3rd party cookie."  To get the browser to save this cookie, you have to set a [P3P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P) header, so the browser knows it's okay to save the cookie.

An example of a valid P3P header would be:

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The image is being loaded on the same domain.  it's being loaded from an include file, would have any affect on using sessions?

Comment: That shouldn't have any effect.  The problem seems to be that when the image is requested, your client isn't sending the current PHP session id.  You do have `session_start();` at the top of your document that outputs the HTML to load the image, correct?

Comment: yes session_start() is at the top of the page that does the image creation.

Comment: nono, not the page that does image creation. I see you have that.  We need it on the page that 1. displays the form the user is filling out (or whatever you're doing) and 2. at the top of the page that is processing the user's input (after they submit the captcha).  If it's not in these 2 places, then the reason you're not getting the `$_SESSION['security_code']` is because the session isn't persisting through all of your pages.

Comment: yes session_start() is at the top of the image creation page and the form that the user fills out which is also the page that submits the form.  So there are 2 pages and both have session_start().